# Google sheets XML parser formula not working

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I'd like to import data from the following link into google sheets: 
http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-02/

I use this formula:

```
=importxml(“http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-02/”;”//Mid”)
```

And I get a formula parse error.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is responding as json, try

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-02/'
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  Logger.log(data.rates[0].mid)
}
```